# How to replace non-ASCII characters

Tags: python, python-2.7, ascii

I have a string in the form`email [ à ] example.com`

I want to make it `email@example.com`.

I tried :

```
print email.replace(u"\xa0", "@")
print email.replace(" [ à ] ", "@")
print email.replace(" à ", "@")
email = email.replace(u" à ", "@")
```

but I always get this error:

> 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 3: ordinal not in range(128)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alternatively, if you don't want to use `unicode` strings, use:

```
In [8]: email = 'email [ à ] domain.fr'

In [9]: email.replace(' [ \xc3\xa0 ] ', '@')
Out[9]: 'email@domain.fr'
```

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I believe it's a better practice to always operate on unicode strings (after decoding any input) instead of replacing raw bytes.

Comment: Fair enough, make sense!

Answer (score 0):

It works if you use the `unicode` type for both the string and replacement:

```
>>> email = u"email [ à ] domain.fr"
>>> email.replace(u" [ à ] ", u"@")
u'email@domain.fr'
```

To get a `unicode` object out of `str` use `.decode()`:

```
email.decode("utf-8")  # or provide another encoding
```